# Why are the Tweet/Follow, Like/Send, Google+1 buttons so finicky?

Tags: html, css, twitter, facebook-like, google-plus

How do I get the Facebook Like/Send button to be positioned at the same height as the other social buttons? I'm pulling my hair out trying to bump the height up!

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/9191/untitled%20folder/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you float all of the blocks, they seem to line up.

```
#tweet, #follow, #plusone, #likesend {
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: any idea if it's possible for me to reduce the space between the Like and Send button?

Comment: I don't think so, since it's in an iFrame. Basic security features will stop you from affecting anything inside it. Unless there is a way to edit the css that comes along with it.

Answer (score 1):

change

```
<div id="LikePluginPagelet">
```

to

```
<div id="LikePluginPagelet" style="margin-bottom: 4px;">
```

and that's it.

[image]
<sub>(source: [phpcode.eu](http://phpcode.eu/images/1314291257.png))</sub>

Comment: any idea if it's possible for me to reduce the space between the Like and Send button?

Comment: margin-left: -7px; to send div (`<div class="fbSendButton fbSendButtonLight fbSendButtonSmall fb....>`)

Comment: div.fbSendButton fbSendButtonLight fbSendButtonSmall fbSendButtonButtonCount { margin-left: -7px; } ?

Answer (score 0):

Try put the Facebookbox in a div and do a margin:-5px 0 0 0; on it

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above, set display:inline-block on the containing div you created.

Comment: I have that as well, but still no go